# Realizacion de un metodo en Java para JTextField y JLabel

Tags: java

En primer lugar, !soy principiante! Así que es una pregunta muy básica la mía en Java.

De que manera puedo hacer para ahorrarme tantas lineas, y crear un método `get()`, con el objetivo de resumir y limpiar la cantidad de codigo para creacion de estos dos tipos de componentes (`JTextField` y `JLabel`)?

Se que no estoy trabajando con `Layouts`, pero, es porque aun no llegue a ver ese tema, y por eso a los componentes `JTextField` y `JLabel`, utilizo el método `setBounds();`

**Observación**: Mi duda es porque, no se como proceder, pues todo lo tengo que crear en el método `public void PaintComponent();`

Gracias y Saludos!

```
    package com.nuevavida.eventodefoco;

import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class LaminaMarco extends JPanel{



    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);

    // CREACION DE JTEXTFIELD

    usuario=new JTextField();

    usuario.setBounds(320, 10, 150, 20);

    add(usuario);

    contrasenia=new JTextField();

    contrasenia.setBounds(320, 50, 150, 20);

    add(contrasenia);

    email=new JTextField();

    email.setBounds(320, 90, 150, 20);

    add(email);

    // CREACION DE JLABEL

    nombreUsuario=new JLabel("Usuario");

    nombreUsuario.setBounds(220, 10, 150, 20);

    add(nombreUsuario);

    nombreContrasenia=new JLabel("Contraseña");

    nombreContrasenia.setBounds(220, 50, 150, 20);

    add(nombreContrasenia);

    nombreEmail=new JLabel("Email");

    nombreEmail.setBounds(220, 90, 150, 20);

    add(nombreEmail);


}

JTextField usuario,contrasenia,email;

JLabel nombreUsuario,nombreContrasenia,nombreEmail;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para ello necesitas utilizar JPanels osea laminas que Contendran los componentes. el Metodo Paint se utiliza mas para colocar imagenes de Fondo y Dibujar figuras Geometricas. y los Layouts se Refiere a la Disposicion de elementos que le das a los JPanel, en este ejemplo utilizare el BorderLayout.

Aqui te aporto un Ejemplo

```
 class EjemploLamina extends JPanel{

       private JPanel lamina;

       private JLabel label;

       private JTextField campo;

       public EjemploLamina(){

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        lamina = new JPanel();

        CreaJTextField(ponle el tamagno);

        CreaJTextField(ponle el tamagno)

        CreaLabels("ponle como quieras");

        CreaLabels("aqui igual");

        add(lamina, BorderLayout.CENTER);

       }

       //METODO PARA LOS JTEXTFIELDS
       public void CreaJTextField(int tamagno){

       campo = new JTextField(tamagno);

       lamina.add(campo);
  }

       //METODO QUE TE REDUCE ESCRIBIR TANTO CODIGO PARA LAS ETIQUETAS
       public void CreaLabels(String nombre){

       label = new JLabel(nombre);

       lamina.add(label);
  }
```

NOTA: Cree un label general, que te servira para hacer tantos labels como quieres, solo tendrias que llamar el metodo cuantas veces quieras, y puedes editarle el tamagno de las letras y todo lo Demas.

IMPORTANTE: la lamina tiene la disposicion por defecto que es la de FlowLayout esta disposicion te coloca los elementos de forma horizontal uno seguido del otro, con los metodos que te di puedes primero agregar un label, luego un JTextField, hasta que consigas una bonita interfaz

CONSEJO: Si quieres aprender JAVA desde basico hasta avanzado te Recomiendo, de donde yo aprendi es un canal de youtube se llama pildorasinformaticas, hay buscar el curso de JAVA tiene 276 videos, que te llevaran hacer un tremendo programador java. SUERTE!!

Comment: Hola! Muchas gracias! Bueno, voy a analizar tu codigo, ya que es lo que buscaba. En realidad, empece por el con el curso de youtube de pildoras informaticas, pero como quise aprender mas, compre el curso de Juan en Udemy, y en esta clase, como aun no vimos Layouts, nos dijo que lo hagamos con el metodo paintComponent(), Mil gracias por tu ayuda! Creo que voy a tener que esperar a ver los Layouts, porque si no, es un lio!